# run excel macro in python and save the results

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pywin32

I have two files, namely **"macro.xlms" and "data.csv"**

I want to run the macro **[Analyze]** from **macro.xmls** file on **data.csv** to generate some data and save the results

So far my code is:

```
macroPath="Macro.xlsm"
filePath="Output.csv"

def performAnalysis():

    if os.path.exists(macroPath):    
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible= True
        excel.Workbooks.Add(filePath)       
        excel.Application.Run(macroPath+"!Analyze")
        excel.Application.Quit()
        del excel
    else:
        print("Error")

def main():
    performAnalysis()

main()
```

When I run the above I get the following error message:-

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"Cannot run the macro 'C:\\Users\\Nabeel\\Desktop\\dense_breasts_experiments\\VolparaOutputExcelMacroOnly_Nov20thV1.xlsm!VolparaAnalyze'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Can anyone please guide me what I am doing wrong ?

Code Edit:

```
def performAnalysis():


    if os.path.exists(macroPath):
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible= True
        excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)  
        excel.Workbooks.Open(macroPath)    
        excel.Application.Run(macroPath+"!Analyze")         

def main():
    performAnalysis()

main()
```

still getting the same error

Comment: Typically you would first open the workbook containing the macro, and then call `Application.Run` on the open workbook.

Comment: With above code, I get the both workbooks opened .. Do you mean open it after adding ?

Comment: I mean first use `Open(macroPath)` and then call `Run`

Comment: I have tried but still the same error. Plz see my edits in code

Comment: Is `Analyze` a Public method in a regular VBA code module ?

Comment: its a Sub .. By default it is public and can be used anywhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68614/discussion-between-user1388142-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Can you run the macro "manually" after opening the workbook in XL?

Comment: yes, I can.. It looks like I am doing something wrong but cannot figure it out

Comment: Is `Macro.xlsm` the actual name of your workbook, or is it something else?  If it's something else, does that name contain any spaces ? If Yes, wrap the name in single-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whcih library are you using but win32com has an option to save changes and all you have to to is add the following line:

```
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
```

Also, `excel` stands for `win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')` after *win32com.client* is imported.

Let me know if it works!